# how to remove std redundant output of python program in vs code ide?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I'm using vs code for python development. I need to unclutter some std output of path whenever i run my python code.

Here below i run "Hello world" in a file any2.py - is there way to remove all that lengthy path before the actual output?

```
PS C:\Users\erjan\Desktop\kkkk>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\erjan\Desktop\kkkk'; &
'C:\python38\python.exe' 'c:\Users\erjan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python-2022.12.1\pythonFiles\lib\python\debugpy\adapter/../..
\debugpy\launcher' '55841' '--' 'c:\Users\erjan\Desktop\kkkk\any2.py'
Hello world!
```

I dont know what this /debugpy/..adapter//launcher is all about, it is sometime tiring to read unrelated output

Comment: if you want to debug your python script you need this `debugpy` stuff, you need to interface with the debug adapter in VSC, there is an option `run without debugger`. The type `python any2.py` yourself, or make a task that executes this command `python ${file}`

Comment: print("\033c") try this before result

Answer (score 0):

> \debugpy\launcher'

You are using **debug mode**:

[image]

You can try `Run Python File`, in front of command, only the path of Python interpreter will be displayed.

[image]

You can also try [code-runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension.

[image]

Then change the settings:

[image]

add the following code to this `setting.json`:

```
"python": "python",
```

Here is the result in terminal:

[image]